# Error for Phpldapadmin after install in php function

Tags: 18.04, php, openldap

this error occurred after install PhpLdapAdmin in ubuntu 18.04 :

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/functions.php on line 1083
&
Unrecognized error number: 8192: Function create_function() is deprecated

How can i fix it ??

Comment: Works for me https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890127 Before you have to upgrade phpLDAPadmin from Git
_______________
KK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programmer who wrote PhpLdapAdmin seems to have used a PHP function called [create_function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). That function is deprecated as of PHP 7.2, which is the version of PHP that comes with Ubuntu 18.04.

If something is "deprecated", it means that it will be removed in a later version. You can imagine it as a heads-up, like "as of now, `create_function()` is still available, but we plan to remove it in a later version of PHP".

What you're seeing is a deprecation *notice*, not necessarily an *error*. If PhpLdapAdmin isn't working properly, there's probably something else wrong as well. But because [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpLDAPadmin) the last release of PhpLdapAdmin is already six years old, I'd strongly recommend to look for a replacement.